# NetBeans GUI Builder: Add gifs to label

Tags: java, animation, netbeans, gif

In the past I have added images to the `jLabel` by `right clicking > Properties > Icon>` and selecting the file from the package of my project (for which I of course had to add the image to my NetBeans Project folder).

Now, I tried the same with `.gif` files and the code doesn't show any error but doesn't run i.e., it shows it is running but there is no frame that I see anywhere. Similar thing happens when I use gifs in `imageIcon` too (code below). Are gifs not supported by swing? I read this somewhere. If this is the case... is there no way to add gif animated images to my GUI frames **in NetBeans**?

Kindly note that I'm doing this through NetBeans... so steps with reference to NetBeans would be appreciated.

```
ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image.gif"));
setIconImage(i1.getImage());
```

Comment: It looks that GIFs are supported (http://www.coderanch.com/t/506909/GUI/java/insert-gif-image-panel), so the problem will probably be a different one.

Comment: I'm doing a small program here, nothing major. Just putting an icon in a frame already provided by the NetBeans GUI Builder. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

no you can add gif images 
get a panel and set its' layout as "Absolute Layout".
(right click on the panel and set layout > Absolute Layout)
then add a label to the panel and clear the text.
then add a gif image to the panel as adding a picture in to the label.
When you run the programme. It works.